# Start date End date validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, datepicker, thymeleaf

I have to validate start date is less than end date and end date is greater than start date using jQuery. Application is using HTML 5 + Thymeleaf.

code :

Validation 1:

```
$('#ValidFrom').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect : ChangeEndDate
});

function ChangeEndDate() {
    var d = $("#ValidFrom").datepicker('getDate'); 
    $('#ValidTo').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        minDate : d, 
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
}
```

Validation 2:

```
$('#ValidTo').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect : ChangeStartDate
});

function ChangeStartDate() {
    var d = $("#ValidTo").datepicker('getDate');  
    $('#ValidFrom').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        maxDate : d, 
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
}
```

If I use either one of the validations it is working fine. But if I use both, only Validation 1 is working. Can anyone help on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

because in your change method you create the datepicker again by calling it and don't pass change listener function again. For example:

```
function ChangeStartDate() {
    var d = $("#ValidTo").datepicker('getDate');
    $('#ValidFrom').datepicker("destroy");
    $('#ValidFrom').datepicker({
        maxDate : d, 
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect : ChangeEndDate
    });
}
```

this way you destroy the datepicker first and then re-initialize it with onSelect method attached. I'm not sure why you remove the class from element, but if you want to destroy the element, removing the class is not the solution. you must call destroy function.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am sorry, can you please clarify me more clearly. Both of the validation works for me when I give only one out of two. But its not working when I give both validation at the sametime. I am not aware of what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the solution. Still the issue is not solved. Only the first validation works. The second doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. You must destroy picker before init this again. And in init picker, you must set option `onSelect`. Hope it help you more

```
$('#ValidFrom').datepicker({ 
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
onSelect : ChangeEndDate});

function ChangeEndDate() {
var d = $("#ValidFrom").datepicker('getDate'); 
$( "#ValidTo" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
$('#ValidTo').datepicker({
    minDate : d, 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect : ChangeStartDate
});}

$('#ValidTo').datepicker({ 
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
onSelect : ChangeStartDate});
function ChangeStartDate() {
var d1 = $("#ValidTo").datepicker('getDate');  
$( "#ValidFrom" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
$('#ValidFrom').datepicker({
    maxDate : d1 , 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect : ChangeEndDate
});}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . I tried the solution  but it didn't work. It didn't disable TO date. Expected is after selecting FROM date, Datepicker in TO date should disable all dates before the selected FROM date. And the vice versa also is not working.

Comment: You try this way: Create new simple html and test again. I think you get a little bit mistake somewhere